# How to serve a React page from Hapijs server regardless of route

Tags: node.js, reactjs, hapi.js

I have a hapijs server serving api routes and a React application.  I serve the react application using inert and a handler with the directory parameters.  However, since the parameters I use in the path {param*} and will automatically serve 'index.html', hapijs will only serve the react page if there are no parameters. This makes sense since hapi will look for the parameter in the directory and respond with an error 404.

Now, what I want to happen is hapi to serve the react page regardless of the parameter (or even the route) and let react take care of the 404 error.  I can't seem to find a legit solution.  Using the directory handler won't allow for 404's, and using the a function handler to serve the page will serve the page without css or js scripts.

I used the following tutorial and read others but to no avail.
https://medium.com/@notrab/using-create-react-app-with-hapi-js-8f4ef3dcd311

```
//manifest.js
module.exports = {
    server: {
        port: process.env.PORT,
        router: { stripTrailingSlash: true },
        routes: {
            files: {relativeTo: path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')},
            cors: {origin: ["*"],}
        }
    },
    register: {
        plugins: [
            { plugin: require('inert') },
            {
                plugin: 'vision',
                options: {
                    engines: { html: require('handlebars') },
                    path: path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')
                }
            },
            {
                plugin: require('./controllers/home'),
            },
        ],
    }
// controller/home
module.exports.register = function(server, options, next) {
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{param*}',
    handler: {
    directory: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "../../../client/build/"),
    listing: false,
    index: ['index.html']
}

// the following handler serves the page but not the css or js
    //handler: (request, h) => {
    //    return h.file("index.html", {confine: false});
    //}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using [Inert](https://github.com/hapijs/inert), since you have the `relativeTo` set to already resolve the `client/build` directory, you do not need to put in the full path again.

You can also completely remove the `index: ['index.html']` since it will default to looking for an index file

```
module.exports.register = function(server, options, next) {
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{param*}',
    handler: {
        directory: { path: '.' }
    }
})
```